# REST API + MongoDb ISODate

Tags: mongodb, date, go, isodate

My GoLang struct:

```
type myPojo struct {
    ID                bson.ObjectId                 `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Start             time.Time                     `json:"start"`
}
```

POST API JSON input request:

```
{
    "Start":ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

My code to convert input JSON request to Golang Struct:

```
func myPostApi(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db mongoDB) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var inputObj myPojo
    err := decoder.Decode(&inputObj)

    if err != nil {
        //This gets executed
        log.Println("Error occurred converting POST input json to myPojo data.")
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Above code is not able to convert, and it goes inside error if block and prints below, please help.

```
2018/02/25 22:12:44 Error occurred converting POST input json to myPojo data.
2018/02/25 22:12:44 invalid character 'I' looking for beginning of value
```

Comment: What was the error, if you print it out?

Comment: Hello @Mark, added error "invalid character 'I' looking for beginning of value" in the main question, thanks for looking into it.

Comment: That error suggests the request body couldn't be decoded because it's not valid json. Look closely at the request body itself, and check it's valid json, according to the [json specification](https://www.json.org).

Answer (score 0):

The

```
ISODate("2013...")
```

value is not valid JSON. That looks like a symbol or function call, neither of which are allowed in JSON. And there is no date type in JSON:

[The "right" JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format)